# Create user in Custom Federal Repository using IBM VMM

Tags: java, websphere, single-sign-on, websphere-8, virtual-member-manager

I am trying to create a new user in a custom LDAP repository (Ex: RepositoryID =custpmRepo) using  IBM Virtual Member Manager API (Java code). Trying to use the IBM code for creating users. But this is creating user in default repository (defaultWIMFileBasedRealm- InternalFileRepository).

IBM Docs referred
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/programmingprereq.html
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/samplecodeforworkingwithusersandgroups.html

Could anyone please guide me on how to create user in custom LDAP repository using VMM API (Java code).
Below is the code which I am using to create user

```
public static void addPersonAccount(String uid, String cn, String sn)
{
    System.out.println("****#### UserAndGroupSample - addPersonAccount - Entering Method");
    try
    {
        locateService(EJB_JNDI_NAME);
        DataObject root = SDOHelper.createRootDataObject();
        DataObject entity = SDOHelper.createEntityDataObject(root, null, 
                SchemaConstants.DO_PERSON_ACCOUNT);
        entity.set("uid", uid);
        entity.set("cn", cn);
        System.out.println("Input data graph before creating user"+ printDO(root));
        // Create the PersonAccount entity
        root = service.create(root);
        System.out.println("Output data graph after creating user"+ printDO(root));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("****#### UserAndGroupSample - addPersonAccount - Exiting Method");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can set the below properties to create user in the desired Custom LDAP Repository (on-default parent or under a different OrgContainer) by setting the parent
user.createDataObject(DO_PARENT).createDataObject(DO_IDENTIFIER).setString(PROP_UNIQUE_NAME, parentDN)
where parentDN is the uniqueName of the parent, like, o=LDAP or ou=sample,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm